# Change fills of a lot of shapes in code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-store-apps

This time I'm developing a windows store app and I've got a problem when I'm trying to change the fill of a lot of rectangles in code. The shapes are too many to name them separately and change their fill separately (There's at least 150 rectangles). They're placed inside a canvas, but Canvas.Children gives me a UIElement value which is not what I want(I want Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle, which I can change their fill). So, any ideas? Thanks a lot.

David,
2015-08-27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

(Edit : Just noticed the vb.net tag; this code is in C#. But the idea is to loop through all the elements inside Canvas.Children and check whether it's a Rectangle, and if it is then change it's Fill)

```
foreach(UIElement child in MyCanvas.Children)
        {
            if(child.GetType()== typeof(Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle))
            {
                ((Rectangle)child).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.AliceBlue);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks work. just need a little time to convert the code.